# "Call Of Duty Modern Warfare HD Remastered" crashes with memory writing error

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have just installed this game. Intro movie starts right after clicking on 'New Game,' but it suddenly exits in the middle of intro playback with this error:

> The instruction at 0xe00fca69 refrenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be written.
>
> Click OK to terminate ...
>
> Click CANCEL to debug ...

It is the same every time (Safe or Normal mode), but sometimes `0xe00fca69` changes to `0xe005ca69`

My hardware configuration is:

> Intel Core i5, 6 GiB Memory, AMD ATI HD 5450 graphic adapter with 2 GiB memory,
>
> Drive C (Windows) 35 GiB free, Drive D (where game is installed) 35 GiB free
>
> OS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: Did you install it on steam? Try verifying the game files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same difficulty while playing this game. I increased my 6gb memory to 8gb. Game still acts very poor on performance but at least it does not exit abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check your RAM.** Yes, new memory can be also faulty. 
   https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/

Just in case the link disappears or does not work, just search for "Windows Memory Diagnostic" in your Start menu. It's available since Windows 7.

It's really easy to do.
If it's "OK"...

2. **Then it may be your Anti-Virus.**
   Try disabling it for a few rounds, see if it helps.

If the game still exists, Google is the way, but I would not keep up my hopes.
The game - even on consoles is very poorly treated by the publisher/developer.